# Get a file from a download inside an iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, download

I want to be able to process a file that gets downloaded from a third party website and for this I am considering opening an `iframe` where the user can login into this specific third party website and there proceed to download the file.

Can I somehow catch that download in order to process the file on my javascript/jquery script in the parent/main site?

Comment: You could not really do this due to security concerns. Most of the browsers disable that. In short you are not enabled to run third party JS files not directly imported in the `DOM`.

Comment: my idea is not to run third party JS. I just want to know if I can have a file that is downloaded in an Iframe and pass it on to my main page. it's not a JS file. it's a XML file which I want to upload back into my backend service.

Comment: You would need js to do so. :) You have to rely on manual upload or a direct call to the service provider. (CORS must be supported by them.)

Comment: I understand. thanks for now @Mark